# Unsuccessful Rerender of Nested Component with JEST/Enzyme React Testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Parent component, App, and a nested component, SearchByForm. SearchByForm contains a radio buttons' group and I am attempting to modifying the third button's value to become checked (true). It can be identified by its className, .workstationRadioBtn.

SearchByForm Class

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchByForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { which: 'order' };
    }

    buttonChange = (e) => {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        this.setState({ which: e.target.value });
        this.props.updateFromSearchByForm(e.target.value);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form className="SearchByForm">
          <div className="form-check">
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="searchBy"
                value="order"
                checked={this.state.which === 'order'}
                onChange={this.buttonChange}
                className="orderRadioBtn"
              />
              Order
              </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check">
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="searchBy"
                value="employee"
                checked={this.state.which === 'employee'}
                onChange={this.buttonChange}
                className="employeeRadioBtn"
              />
              Employee
              </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check">
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="searchBy"
                value="workstation"
                checked={this.state.which === 'workstation'}
                onChange={this.buttonChange}
                className="workstationRadioBtn"
              />
              Work Station
              </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  export default SearchByForm;
```

Search Component class:

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchKey: '_id', searchBy: 'order', searchResults: null };
    this.updateFromSearchByForm = this.updateFromSearchByForm.bind(this);
    this.updateFromKeysForm = this.updateFromKeysForm.bind(this);
    this.clearSearchResults = this.clearSearchResults.bind(this);
    this.populateSearchResults = this.populateSearchResults.bind(this);
  }

  updateFromSearchByForm(value) {
    this.setState({ searchBy: value });
  }

  updateFromKeysForm(value) {
    this.setState({ searchKey: value });
  }

  keyToSearchBy = () => {
    switch (this.state.searchBy) {
      case 'order':
        return (
          <KeysForm which='order' updateFromKeysForm={this.updateFromKeysForm}></KeysForm>
        );
      case 'employee':
        return (
          <KeysForm which='employee' updateFromKeysForm={this.updateFromKeysForm}></KeysForm>
        );
      case 'workstation':
        return (
          <KeysForm which='workstation' updateFromKeysForm={this.updateFromKeysForm}></KeysForm>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <KeysForm which='order' updateFromKeysForm={this.updateFromKeysForm}></KeysForm>
        );
    }
  }

  clearSearchResults = () => {
    this.setState({ searchResults: null });
  }

  populateSearchResults = (results) => {
    this.setState({ searchResults: results });
  }

  displayOrderResults = () => {
    let list = [];
    let count = 0;
    list.push(<label> Orders found that match your search criteria:</label>)
    for (let result of this.state.searchResults) {
      list.push(
        <ListGroupItem key={count}>ID: {result._id}, OrderID: {result.OrderID}, CustomerID: {result.CustomerID}, DateRequired: {result.DateRequired}, Status: {result.Status}, PriorityFlag: {result.PriorityFlag}</ListGroupItem>
      )
      count++;
    }
    return list;
  }

  displayEmployeeResults = () => {
    let list = [];
    let count = 0;
    list.push(<label> Employees found that match your search criteria:</label>)
    for (let result of this.state.searchResults) {
      list.push(
        <ListGroupItem key={count}>ID: {result._id}, Staff Name: {result.WorkerName}</ListGroupItem>
      )
      count++;
    }
    return list;
  }

  displayWorkStationResults = () => {
    let list = [];
    let count = 0;
    list.push(<label> Stations found that match your search criteria:</label>)
    for (let result of this.state.searchResults) {
      list.push(
        <ListGroupItem key={count}>ID: {result._id}, Work Station Name: {result.StationName}</ListGroupItem>
      )
      count++;
    }
    return list;
  }

  showSearchResults = () => {
    //Know how to display based on searchBy type.
    switch (this.state.searchBy) {
      case 'order':
        return (this.displayOrderResults());
      case 'employee':
        return (this.displayEmployeeResults());
      case 'workstation':
        return (this.displayWorkStationResults());
      default:
        break;
    }
    for (let result of this.state.searchResults) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Jumbotron>
        <div className="App">
          <div className='header'>
            <div className='header-space1'>
              <div className='button-header'>
                <Link to='/menu'>
                  <Button id='menu'>Back to Menu</Button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='header-space2'>
              <h2>Search</h2>
            </div>
            <div className='header-space3'>
              <div className='button-header'>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='Search'>
            <div className='Row'>
              <div className='SearchForm'>
                <p>What would you like to search by?</p>
                <SearchByForm updateFromSearchByForm={this.updateFromSearchByForm}></SearchByForm>
                {this.keyToSearchBy()}
              </div>
            </div>
            <ValueForm searchKey={this.state.searchKey} searchBy={this.state.searchBy} clearSearchResults={this.clearSearchResults} populateSearchResults={this.populateSearchResults}></ValueForm>
            <br></br>
            <div className='Row'>
              <div className='SearchResults'>
                <p>Search Results</p>
                {this.state.searchResults ?
                  <ListGroup>
                    {this.showSearchResults()}
                  </ListGroup>
                  :
                  null}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Jumbotron>
    );
  }

}
```

The test currently creates a full tree copy and successfully checks the .workstationRadioBtn's checked value to true. It also successfully changes the 'which' state field of SearchByForm to 'workstation'.
My test's current state is as follows

```
describe('Work Station Search', () => {
    it(' successfully selects order radio button', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <Router>
                <Search />
            </Router>
        );
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        const wrapperSearchByForm = wrapper.find(SearchByForm);
        wrapperSearchByForm.find('input').filter('.workstationRadioBtn').simulate('change', {target: {checked: true}});
        wrapperSearchByForm.setState({ which: 'workstation' });
        wrapper.update();
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
    })
});
```

The debug code of the test shows the above to be true, however the update() doesn't appear to have successfully rerendered the second nested component, KeysForm, whose returned render is dependent upon the SearchByForm. It is still acting as though the Order radio button is checked.

Here is the test's full debug output:

```
console.log src/__tests__/Search/Search.test.js:84
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router history={{...}}>
          <Search>
            <Jumbotron fluid={false}>
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <div className="App">
                  <div className="header">
                    <div className="header-space1">
                      <div className="button-header">
                        <Link to="/menu">
                          <LinkAnchor href="/menu" navigate={[Function: navigate]}>
                            <a href="/menu" onClick={[Function: onClick]}>
                              <Button id="menu" variant="primary" active={false} disabled={false} type="button">
                                <button id="menu" disabled={false} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                                  Back to Menu
                                </button>
                              </Button>
                            </a>
                          </LinkAnchor>
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="header-space2">
                      <h2>
                        Search
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="header-space3">
                      <div className="button-header" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="Search">
                    <div className="Row">
                      <div className="SearchForm">
                        <p>
                          What would you like to search by?
                        </p>
                        <SearchByForm updateFromSearchByForm={[Function: bound updateFromSearchByForm]}>
                          <form className="SearchByForm">
                            <div className="form-check">
                              <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="order" checked={true} onChange={[Function]} className="orderRadioBtn" />
                                Order
                              </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check">
                              <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="employee" checked={false} onChange={[Function]} className="employeeRadioBtn" />
                                Employee
                              </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check">
                              <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="workstation" checked={false} onChange={[Function]} className="workstationRadioBtn" />
                                Work Station
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </SearchByForm>
                        <KeysForm which="order" updateFromKeysForm={[Function: bound updateFromKeysForm]}>
                          <div className="KeysForm">
                            <div className="OrderKeys">
                              <p>
                                Which Order Key would you like to search by?
                              </p>
                              <form>
                                <div className="form-check">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="orderKey" value="_id" checked={true} onChange={[Function]} className="form-check-input" />
                                    Id
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-check">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="orderKey" value="DateRequired" checked={false} onChange={[Function]} className="form-check-input" />
                                    Date Required
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-check">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="orderKey" value="Status" checked={false} onChange={[Function]} className="form-check-input" />
                                    Status
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-check">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="orderKey" value="PriorityFlag" checked={false} onChange={[Function]} className="form-check-input" />
                                    Priority Flag
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </KeysForm>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <ValueForm searchKey="_id" searchBy="order" clearSearchResults={[Function: bound ]} populateSearchResults={[Function: bound ]}>
                      <form className="ValueForm">
                        <label>
                          <input type="text" name="value" value="" onChange={[Function]} />
                        </label>
                        <Button onClick={[Function]} variant="primary" active={false} disabled={false} type="button">
                          <button onClick={[Function]} disabled={false} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                            Search
                          </button>
                        </Button>
                      </form>
                    </ValueForm>
                    <br />
                    <div className="Row">
                      <div className="SearchResults">
                        <p>
                          Search Results
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Jumbotron>
          </Search>
        </Router>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Can you debug the state after this line ` wrapperSearchByForm.setState({ which: 'workstation' }); ` ? Make sure the state was updated!

Comment: Great suggestion thanks! It appears as though state is correctly updating - here's the output when I run console.log(wrapperSearchByForm.state()) after wrapper.update(): 
console.log src/__tests__/Search/Search.test.js:90
      { which: 'workstation' }

Comment: Could it be a conflict as, despite the .update(), the nested KeysForm component is passed a which prop set to 'order'? Seen here in the debug output: <KeysForm which="order" updateFromKeysForm={[Function: bound updateFromKeysForm]}>

Comment: Can you please post `Search` as well? I want to run the code on my machine, I'm curious about `updateFromKeysForm` function

Comment: Of course - posted in the above. A bit of explanation that may help: there's two layers to the form. searchBy means the element and searchKey is the field/key of the value we want to search for.

Comment: There are still some dependencies that I need to run the code, can you create a react project on https://codesandbox.io/ ?